# Some suggested enhancements and/or fixes for Open Source AMD Graphics Cards drivers?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, graphics, ati

I have a Dell Inspiron n5010 (2010 model). It has an AMD Raedon HD 5470 graphics chip in it. Its running Kubuntu 14.04 (current kernel 4.2.0-34). Although the open source drivers work fine, but there are some glaring issues like screen tearing, about 5 degrees (Celcius) more hotter on average use (compared to Windows), corrupted text (sometimes, most notable in pop-ups in Google Chrome), and so on.

Are there any general set of fixes or command parameters that you could suggest to fully or partially solve these issues (and more if possible)?

Answer (score 0):

If google chrome is having issues using the AMD GPU, it's better to turn of hardware acceleration off in Chrome settings. For me chrome did not render pages correctly, and it was very annoying when you switched tabs or resize windows.

This is how to turn off hardware acceleration. Open Google Chrome and goto Settings. Scroll down to the bottom of the page and click on "Show advanced settings". Simply uncheck 'Use hardware acceleration when available' and restart chrome.

Comment: Turning Off hardware acceleration makes the YouTube videos more choppy and laggy. So, thanks but do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Your CPU is not able to do the graphics rendering. I will still leave the answer here as it may help someone else with a powerful CPU. Open chrome from a terminal and see if it prints some errors to the terminal.

Comment: CPU is a capable i5 430. No errors in the terminal.